# Is there a way to avoid redundant computations by warps in a thread block on partially overlapped arrays

Tags: cuda

I want to design a CUDA kernel that has thread blocks where warps read their own 1-D arrays. Suppose that a thread block with two warps takes two arrays {1,2,3,4} and {2,4,6,8}. Then each of warps would perform some computations by reading their own arrays. The computation is done based on per-array element basis. This means that the thread block would have redundant computations for the elements 2 and 4 in the arrays.
Here is my question: How I can avoid such redundant computations?

Precisely, I want to make a warp skip the computation of an element once the element has been already touched by other warps, otherwise the computation goes normally because any warps never touched the element before.

Using a hash table on the shared memory dedicated into a thread block may be considered. But I worry about performance degradation due to hash table accesses whenever a warp access elements of an array.

Any idea or comments?

Comment: You are going to have to explain this better. Why does it mean "that the thread block would have redundant computations for the elements 2 and 4 in the arrays"?

Answer (score 1):

In parallel computation on many-core co-processors, it is desired to perform arithmetic operations on an independent set of data, i.e. to eliminate any sort of dependency on the set of vectors which you provide to threads/warps. In this way, the computations can run in parallel. If you want to keep track of elements that you have been previously computed (in this case, 2 and 4 which are common in the two input arrays), you have to serialize and create branches which in turn diminishes the computing performance.

In conclusion, you need to check if it is possible to eliminate redundancy at the input level by reducing the input vectors to those with different components. If not, skipping redundant computations of repeated components may not necessarily improve the performance, since the computations are performed in batch.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try to understand what happens on the hardware level.

First of all, computation in CUDA happens via warps. A warp is a group of 32 threads which are synchronized to each other. An instruction is executed on all the threads of a corresponding warp at the same time instance. So technically it's not threads but the warps that finally executes on the hardware.

Now, let us suppose that somehow you are able to keep track of which elements does not need computation so you put a condition in the kernel like

```
...
if(computationNeeded){
    compute();
}
else{
    ...
}
...
```

Now let us assume that there are 5 threads in a particular warp for which "computationNeeded" is false and the don't need computation. But according to our definition, all threads executes the same instruction. So even if you put these conditions all threads have to execute both if and else blocks.

Exception:
It will be faster if all the threads of a particular block execute either if or else condition. But its exceptional case for almost all the real-world algorithms.

Suggestion
Put a pre-processing step either on CPU or GPU, which eliminate the redundant elements from input data. Also, check if this step is worth.

> Precisely, I want to make a warp skip the computation of an element once the element has been already touched by other warps, otherwise the computation goes normally because any warps never touched the element before.
>
> Using a hash table on the shared memory dedicated into a thread block
>   may be considered

If you want inter-warp communication between ALL the warps of the grid then it is only possible via global memory not shared memory.